# JPG join MP3 to FLV

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, flv, jpeg

How to convert image and music to video? I would like YouTube video. I like FFMPEG command or other Ubuntu free software. I would like: *.mp3 + *.jpg = *.flv

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a recent `ffmpeg` syntax:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i music.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -tune stillimage -c:a copy output.mkv
```

This example will copy the audio instead of re-encoding to preserve quality. Adjust quality if desired with the CRF option. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more information.

[Super User](http://superuser.com) (another StackExchange site) is a better place for `ffmpeg` usage questions since Stack Overflow is programming specific.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was in need of merging an image and an audio file into a video file. Since none of the answers that I found on SO worked for me, I'm leaving here what worked for me after trial and error:

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 205 -i audio.mp3 -i image.jpg -crf 20 test.flv`

Where `205` is the duration of the input mp3 file in seconds -> 3:25 minutes.
*(Tested with FFmpeg SVN-r13582)*